# What are module signatures in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-backpack

I have recently found Haskell's feature called "module signatures". As I have discovered they are put in `.hsig` files and begin with `signature` keyword instead of `module`.
The example syntax of such a file may look like

```
signature Str where

data Str
empty :: Str
append :: Str -> Str -> Str
```

However, I cannot imagine how and why one would use them. Could you explain me which problems do they solve and how to properly make use of them?

They strongly remind me the module system that one can see in OCaml ([link](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html)), which also has modules signatures and separate implementations, but I can't decide how close are these two concepts. Is it somehow related?

Comment: Have you looked at [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Module_signature) and the [relevant GHC trac page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Backpack)? They seem to provide a pretty good overview and plenty of links to uses in existing packages. There's also [a paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/backpack.pdf) which seems to cover the motivation and design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are related to the OCaml module system, but with some important differences:

- Signatures are defined within the language (in **.hsig** files) but unlike in OCaml they are *not* instantiated within the language. Instead, the package manager controls instantiation (currently, only Cabal provides that). Modules never know if they are importing an abstract signature or an actual module.
- Implementation modules know nothing about signatures and do not not reference them directly. Any existing module can implement a signature if the definitions happen to be compatible.
- Instantiation is triggered by a coincidence of module name and signature name in the dependencies of some compilation unit (executable, library, test suite...) When the names coincide, a process called "signature matching" takes place that verifies that the types and definitions are compatible.

The "happy path" is that in your program you depend on some library having a signature "hole", and also on another library that provides an implementation module with the same name. Then signature matching happens automatically. When the names don't match, or we need multiple instantiations of the signature-using library, we have to rename signatures and/or modules in the [mixins](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-mixins) section of the Cabal file.

---

As for why module signatures might be useful, consider [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring), the most popular library by far for handling binary data in Haskell. But there are others, for example [stdio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stdio) with its [`Bytes`](http://winterland.me/2019/02/17/stdio-A-simple-and-high-performance-IO%20toolkit-for-Haskell/) type.

Suppose you are writing your own library that uses binary data, and you don't want to force your users into either stdio or [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring). What are your choices?

- One would be to create something like a `Bytelike` class and parameterize all your functions with it. You would also need to add a type parameter to *every* data type that contains bytes.
- Another would be to create a signature that defines an abstract binary data type and all the operations that are required of it. Your library would make use of the signature, and remain "indefinite" until the user depends both on your library and a suitable implementation when creating his own libraries.

From the perspective of the user, the typeclass solution is unsatisfactory. The user knows that he wants to use either `ByteString` or `Bytes`, just one of them. The decision will not depend on some runtime flag and will remain constant across the extent of *his* program. And yet he has to deal with a more complex API that reminds him of that already decided issue at every turn.

It's better if he makes the decision once, writes it in his .cabal file, and deals with a simpler API from then onwards.

Comment: Here's an interesting comment on typecasses vs. signatures for modularity by the creator of Backpack http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/09/the-base-of-a-string-theory-for-haskell/#comment-21258

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Module_signature), they're quite closely related to OCaml module signatures. They allow you to create a package missing some modules and say these modules, containing such and such types and values, should be delivered by package's user. I haven't tested it myself, but I imagine that such a package works very much like an OCaml functor.

Comment: I have never used that feature, but I think that, if we compare it to OCaml functors, it should work as an OCaml functor _which can be only instantiated once_. If my intuition is correct, that greatly diminishes the power wrt real OCaml functors.

Comment: @chi One can instantiate a signature-using library multiple times, it requires making multiple renamed "copies" of the library modules—and of the signature they require—by means of the `mixins` clause of the Cabal file. Here's an example: https://github.com/danidiaz/really-small-backpack-example/tree/master/lesson2-signatures Renaming modules is pretty intuitive (and a better alternative to `-XPackageImports`) but renaming a required *signature* in a library in order to match some implementation module feels a bit unintuitive at first.

Comment: @danidiaz Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of this renaming feature. That seems to really change the game, since without being able to rename the signature, only a single implementation of that seemed possible. Using such renaming, we should indeed get something very close to OCaml functors.